# How to you return a customized error page when a MySQL disconnects while a user is using an app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, error-handling

Instead of showing an 500 screen that says there is a connectionException, I would like to customize a view for this specific situation.

I currently have an CustomErrorController which redirects a user to the top page which is /todoLists when the user tries to access a URL that does not exist.

I'm having trouble with implementing the code which returns a view in the error directory titled database.html.

```
package com.teamlab.todolist.web;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.net.ConnectException;


@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @GetMapping("/error")
    String backToTopPage() {
        return "redirect:/todoLists";
    }

    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/internalServerError";
    }
//
//    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
//    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
//    public String connectionErrorHandling(ConnectException e) {
//        return "/internalServerError";
//    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ConnectException.class)
    public String connectionErrorHandling(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        return "/internalServerError";
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you debug and check if your `connectionErrorHandling` is called? If not: is the endpoint causing the `ConnectionException` declared in this controller? If not: see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know how you structured your project and I don't know if your `connectionErrorHandling`-method is called, I assume that the handling is not called, because the endpoint, causing this exception, is declared in another controller.

If that's the case, you're looking for `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(TheExceptionYouWantToHandle.class)
  public String handleYourException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){

    return "name_of_view_you_want_to_show";
  }
}
```

This will catch the exception you want to catch and redirect to the view with the name you return by your `@ExceptionHandler`

If you just want to handle exceptions inside a specific controller, or you want to handle the same exception in different controllers in a different way, you can declare your `@ExceptionHandler`inside this controller. When you use `@ControllerAdvice` the `@ExceptionHandler`s are registered for all controllers.

Comment: Made some edits to reflect what I have now, you are right in that connectionErrorHandling is not being called...dont know what to do from this point...

Comment: Have tried my suggestion to declare the `@ExceptionHandler` in a separate class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`?

Comment: I havn't tried yet since I couldn't figure out where to put the class. Any suggestions? Also would it be ok to include my code for when a user tries to access a URL that does not exist into the class you are recommending me to make?

Comment: You can handle as much exceptions into this class as you want. I would keep the logic in this class to a minimum and so only code required to handle a specific exception should be put here. But before discussing about architectural decisions we should make it work ;) So just give it a try and then check how you can optimize your architecture.